# Countable choice and totally bounded metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Can we prove that the following statement is equivalent to the axiom of countable choice (CC)?

> If every sequence in a metric space $X$ has a Cauchy subsequence, then $X$ is totally bounded.

Note: CC is known to be equivalent to the above condition with "metric space" replaced by "pseudometric space".

Comment: Can you please give the definition of CC, what is it?

Comment: @ThePortakal: Axiom of countable choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks

Comment: Where did you come across this question, and where did you come across the solution you posted in your answer? You say it's from an answer I wrote, but it's not in there.

Comment: same paper you mentioned. There it was for pseudometric space. I thought this must be true for metric space but as in your comments. I think it may not be. But in y question I'll add words, is it true in metric spaces. @AsafKaragila

Comment: I should have been careful while asking the question. @AsafKaragila

Comment: I took the liberty of rephrasing your question; I had a little trouble understanding the original wording.  Feel free to make further edits if you prefer something different.

Comment: @AsafKaragila although you deleted your answer. But can we prove countable choice for finite set exist using trick in your answer under given assumption

Answer (score 0):

I found a proof in case we work with pseudometric space instead of metric space.
If CC fails then PCC fails. [Equivalent of the countable axiom of choice?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/287839/168520)

So there exist sequence of non empty sets such that each sequence meets only finitely many of Xn. 
Now we define sequence X = Xn*{n) with metric
d[(x,m), (y,n)] = 0 if n=m and 1 otherwise.

(It works in pseudometric space, can we use same set with slight change in metric for metric space case)

Comment: I don't see any obvious way to adapt this proof to metric spaces.  Intuitively, I would like to equip each $X_n$ with a totally bounded metric $d_n$, and then consider the metric $d(x,y) = d_n(x,y)$ if $x,y \in X_n$ and $d(x,y) = 1$ otherwise.  But at least in ZFC, sets of cardinality greater than $\mathfrak{c}$ don't have totally bounded metrics (if it did, its completion would be compact, and compact metric spaces are separable and so have cardinality at most $\mathfrak{c}$).

Comment: @NateEldredge sorry didn'y get what you want to say. Totally bounded implies sequential bounded. This is true in ZF only. So we should rather try to find a sequential bounded set which is not totally bounded(if possible)